# How can I make a full text index of the column?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my current migration:

```
class News extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('News', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('imgPath')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('News');
    }
}
```

Now I need to make a full text index on these columns separately: `title` `description`. So I'm looking for something like this: `->fulltext()`. But I don't find anything similar in the Laravel documentation.

Anyway,

1. how can I make a full text index on a single column in migration? Like: `(title)`
2. Also for my information, how can I make a composite full text index on multiple columns in migration? Like: `(title, description)`

---

**Note:** I want an intex that lets me search like this: `. . . match(col) against('value')`

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fulltext-indexes-at-migrations

Comment: People shouldn't down vote good questions, it discourages members.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Laravel doesn't support FULLTEXT search.
But you can use raw queries as:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE News ADD FULLTEXT search(title, description)');
```

*Note - that if you are not using MySQL 5.6+ we must set the Database Engine to MyISAM instead of InnoDB.*

```
$table->engine = 'MyISAM'; // means you can't use foreign key constraints
```

For searching, you can do as:

```
$q = Input::get('query');

->whereRaw("MATCH(title,description) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q))
```

Comment: It's not Mysql Specific https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql

Answer (score 13):

[Laravel 9+](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#available-index-types) now fully supports full text index.
To define a full index column use the below

```
$table->fullText('body');
```

And you can also use the **whereFullText** in your query

```
User::whereFullText('body', 'john doe')->get();
```

Note: Laravel 8+ support the fullText index but there's no option for Where clause

Comment: Here's also short demo: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-9/episodes/9

Answer (score 3):

Since Laravel release 8.79 full text search was implemented for PostgreSQL and MySQL [Pull Request on GitHub "[8.x] Implement Full-Text Search for MySQL & PostgreSQL"](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40129)

So, now you can easily not just add an fulltext index to a column but perform a query on it with Eloquent:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // ...
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        // ...
        $table->fullText(['title', 'description'])->language('english');
    });
}
```

And you of course can use your index to execute some queries using Eloquent:

```
News::whereFullText->(['title', 'description'], 'YOUR_QUERY_TEXT')->get();
```

Also check the documentation: [Laravel 8.x - Available index types](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-index-types)

Answer (score 1):

$table->fulltext(['title', 'description']);
you can also use it like above
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes

Answer (score 0):

Be aware! The answer before is correct but if you're testing your app and you are using sqlite (memory) this command will fail!
Check the database type

```
if( getenv('DB_CONNECTION') === 'mysql' ) // or something else
```